# SELECT COL HIVE SQL VALUE WHERE VALUES <5000

Tags: sql, hive, mapreduce, apache-pig

I'm learning about HIVE and I have come across a question I cannot seem to find a workable answer for. I have to extract all of the numeric columns that ONLY contain integer values <5000 from a table and create a space separated text file. I am familiar with creating text files and selecting rows but selecting columns that meet a specific parameter I am not familiar with, any help or guidance will be appreciated! Below I've listed the structure of the table. Also, there is an image attached showing the data in table format. For OUTPUT I need to go through ALL the COLUMNS and RETURN ONLY the the COLUMNS that meet the parameter of integer values LESS THAN 5000.

```
create table lineorder (
  lo_orderkey          int,
  lo_linenumber        int,
  lo_custkey           int,
  lo_partkey           int,
  lo_suppkey           int,
  lo_orderdate         int,
  lo_orderpriority     varchar(15),
  lo_shippriority      varchar(1),
  lo_quantity          int,
  lo_extendedprice     int,
  lo_ordertotalprice   int,
  lo_discount          int,
  lo_revenue           int,
  lo_supplycost        int,
  lo_tax               int,
  lo_commitdate         int,
  lo_shipmode          varchar(10)
)
```

[Data in tbl format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQveJ.png)

Comment: Hint: Use `WHERE`.  As for selecting only numeric columns, it might be easiest for you to just list out the columns you want in your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want to produce for sample data.

Comment: I would love to just select them manually but unfortunately I have to do it via SQL statements.

Comment: What have you tried? What did not work?

Comment: I haven't tried either, I reported the comments and suggestions back to my professor for further elaboration and I am awaiting his reply.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional columns selecting is a **terrible**, **horrible**, **no good**, **very bad** idea.

Being that said, here is a demo.

```
with    t as 
        (
            select      stack
                        (
                            3

                           ,10 ,100  ,1000 ,'X' ,null
                           ,20 ,null ,2000 ,'Y' ,200000
                           ,30 ,300  ,3000 ,'Z' ,300000
                        ) as (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)
        )


select  regexp_replace
        (
            printf(concat('%s',repeat(concat(unhex(1),'%s'),field(unhex(1),t.*,unhex(1))-2)),*)
           ,concat('([^\\x01]*)',repeat('\\x01([^\\x01]*)',field(unhex(1),t.*,unhex(1))-2))
           ,c.included_columns
        )       as record

from    t

       cross join      (select  ltrim
                                (
                                    regexp_replace
                                    (
                                        concat_ws(' ',sort_array(collect_set(printf('$%010d',pos+1))))
                                       ,concat
                                        (
                                            '( ?('
                                           ,concat_ws
                                            (
                                                '|'
                                               ,collect_set
                                                (
                                                    case 
                                                        when    cast(pe.val as int) >= 5000
                                                             or cast(pe.val as int) is null

                                                        then    printf('\\$%010d',pos+1)
                                                    end
                                                )
                                            ) 
                                           ,'))|(?<=\\$)0+'
                                        )
                                       ,''
                                    ) 
                                )       as included_columns

                        from    t
                                lateral view posexplode(split(printf(concat('%s',repeat(concat(unhex(1),'%s'),field(unhex(1),*,unhex(1))-2)),*),'\\x01')) pe
                        ) c
```

---

```
+---------+
| record  |
+---------+
| 10 1000 |
| 20 2000 |
| 30 3000 |
+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think hive supports variable substitution in the function. So you would have to write a shell scripts that executes the first query which returns the required columns.Then you can assign it to a variable in shell script and then create a new query for creating files in local directory and run it via hive -e from bash.

```
create table t1(x int , y int) ; // table used for below query
```

Sample bash script :

```
cols =hive -e 'select concat_ws(',', case when min(x) > 5000 then 'x' end , case when min(y) > 5000 then 'y' end) from t1'
query ="INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY <directory name> ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' select  $cols from t1 "
hive -e query
```